# Differences in behavior between input and label in div

Tags: html, css

Ok, so the title isn't the best but I couldn't think of a simple way to summarize my question.... so here goes.

I have an input type of text (inline-block element--> or at least that is what the browser sets it as) and i have a label(inline) within a div(block).

The question is based on doing a text-overflow: ellipsis. I found some differences between the behavior of placing the traits in the input vs the div holding the label. Based on specs it says that you HAVE to have an overflow that isn't visible. I wasn't required to have that on the input. My question is just... .WHY?    I don't like when things behave differently than I expect and not knowing the why's (I dont' take things for face value... i need to know the details. I have a sample snippet of code here to show what I mean.

http://www.cssdesk.com/hYgpy

Its a cheesy example but I needed simplicity for testing it. If you remove the overflow: hidden from div...the ellipsis doesn't work anymore...but its not required for input at all.....why, whyyyyy *throwing herself on her knees...screaming at the heavens*

:) thanks in advance

Comment: why do we go at a green light and stop at a red light? because a committee decided that was the way it was going to be.

Comment: i know....fair enough if that is the true answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm actually afraid of posting this as an answer, as I can't back this up with documentation, but I'll try to share some enlightenment.

HTML input controls (such as `input` `select` `textarea`) have user agent's defined behaviors, that in some ways may seem to defy the common properties we see in other elements.

The input field for example, has a built-in overflow, designed to keep the typed text from expanding the element. It is naturally applied by it's `-prefix-appearance` property, and you can't change it. Try forcing an `overflow: visible;` to the input, and see that you won't show the overflowed text.

```html
<input type="text" style="overflow:visible;width: 70px;" value="This text is not entirely visible" />
```

Therefore, the `text-overflow: ellipsis` will work at this kind of element, since the inner hidden behavior of it's overflow is naturallly implied to it.

Comment: OMG!!! AWESOME EXPLANATION!!! THANK YOU SOOOOOOOO MUCH. I know its a simple question but I'm "OBSESSED" with knowing whys and now that I know, well it totally makes sense and I can move on :)


By the way, how did you find that out. Like knowing where to find this information for myself would be so valuable. I looked in chrome dev tools at the input and I see the -webkit-appearance is 'textfield' but after looking into MDN for it, it doesn't specifically say the extra info you provided..like the inner overflow. 

Thanks so much!!!